# MotionLayout ignores KeyFrameSet

Tags: android, xml, android-motionlayout

I'm trying to rotateY a topCard for the first part of animation, and to rotateY a bottomCard for the second. To hold bottomCard untill it's time I use KeyFragmentSet. When I click on the topCard MotionLayout ignores KeyFragmentSet and just rotateY both cards simultaneously for the whole animation time.

Tried ti replace XML onClick with setOnClickListener, but the same thing happens.

MotionScene:

```
<MotionScene
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition android:id="@+id/flip_transition"
        app:constraintSetEnd="@+id/bottom"
        app:constraintSetStart="@+id/top"
        app:duration="1500">

        <OnClick app:targetId="@id/CL_top_card"
            app:clickAction="transitionToEnd"/>

        <KeyFrameSet android:id="@+id/flip_keyFrameSet">
            <KeyAttribute
                app:targetId="@+id/CL_top_card"
                app:framePosition="50"
                android:rotationY="90"/>

            <KeyAttribute
                app:targetId="@+id/CL_bottom_card"
                app:framePosition="50"
                android:rotationY="-90"/>
        </KeyFrameSet>

    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/top">

        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/CL_top_card"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="40dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:rotationY="0"/>

        <Constraint
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="40dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:id="@id/CL_bottom_card"
            android:rotationY="-90"/>
    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet
        android:id="@+id/bottom">

        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/CL_top_card"
            android:rotationY="90"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="40dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

        <Constraint
            android:id="@id/CL_bottom_card"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="40dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:rotationY="0"/>
    </ConstraintSet>

</MotionScene>
```

xml layout:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.constraint.motion.MotionLayout
    android:id="@+id/ML_trust_card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/scene_flip">


    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/CL_top_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:rotationY="0">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tx_task_question"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="40dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="TOPtopTOPtopTop00000000000000000000000"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/CL_bottom_card"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:rotationY="-90">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tx_task_answer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="40dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="bottombottombottombottom"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.constraint.motion.MotionLayout>
```

I use:

implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:2.0.0-beta2'

I expect the topCard rotateY from 0 to 90 firstly and the bottomCard rotateY from -90 to 0 lastly

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Just replace app:targetId with app:motionTarget in KeyAttributes.